# Why is GROUP BY neglecting some records?

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

```
Configurations
1.  configname
2.  configvalue
3.  otherDataInstanceId

OtherData
1.  dataname
2.  datavalue
3.  instanceId
```

Configuration's `otherDataInstanceId` links to OtherData's `instanceId` column.  I executed the following query against the data I have in MySQL:

```
SELECT other.datavalue AS time_stamp, 
configs.configname AS configuration_name, 
configs.configvalue AS configuration_value 

FROM Configurations configs 
JOIN OtherData other 

WHERE configs.otherDataInstanceId=other.instanceId 
AND other.dataname='timestamp' 

GROUP BY configuration_name;
```

I expected to see these results:

```
2012-01-02 16:05:48      Voltage         10 volts
2000-01-01 12:00:09      Voltage         8 volts
2013-06-01 01:12:32      Voltage         28 volts
2013-07-01 01:12:32      Voltage         5 volts
```

Instead I only see:

```
2012-01-02 16:05:48      Voltage         10 volts
```

I've been searching online and `GROUP BY` is supposed to take results and group rows by the specified column; so in my database if I eliminate the GROUP BY I see multiple `configname`s with the same value (`'Voltage'`).  So it should group them next to each other.  But I only see 1 row for `'Voltage'`, not 4 - WHY?

Comment: [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) *"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. "*

Comment: In addition to @FreshPrinceOfSO comment, it might be helpful if you showed the data from each table. Why do you think you need to use GROUP BY?

Comment: I love these MySQL ANSI standard extensions.

Comment: @Phil MySQL ANSI standard....where? what's that?  I didn't think MySQL and ANSI standard went hand in hand?

Comment: @IMSoP Whoops. Saw "DABA" in the username

Comment: @Phil Shouldn't you be sleeping?

Comment: You may be need WHERE configs.configname='Voltage' Instead GROUP BY

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the non-standard GROUP BY semantics - whether it resulted in an error or indeterminate values, this query can never return the rows the OP wants.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA Unfortunately for you, the answer is actually the first comment

Comment: @Phil Are you sure? How does that comment explain the difference between a 4-row result set and a 1-row one? I think you're all so eager to dis MySQL that you haven't fully read the question.

Comment: @IMSoP Not using ANSI standard `GROUP BY` makes my Tourette's flair up.

Comment: @IMSoP I've read the question - the query makes no sense without an aggregate function and wouldn't even parse properly in a proper RDBMS. What the FreshPrinceOfSO linked to explained the incorrect behaviour, which has obviously confused the OP.

Comment: @Phil The final question is "But I only see 1 row for Voltage, not 4-WHY?" to which the answer is "because you're using GROUP BY", nothing to do with aggregates and MySQL's laxness.

Comment: @IMSoP My point is, MySQL should not allow invalid SQL that returns crap data! Try it on SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres...

Comment: @Phil My point is **that is completely irrelevant to the OP's problem**. If they had written this query on a different DBMS, they would have got an error, which I agree is a Good Thing, **but that still wouldn't be the result they wanted**.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Indeed, allowing ambiguous queries like this is an abomination, and it's possible a proper error message would have been less confusing to the OP than the invalid result. But pointing to the documentation about how that abomination works doesn't help explain the fact that the OP doesn't actually need to GROUP BY at all.

Comment: @IMSoP: While I agree with you that the main issue is likely not the GROUP BY extensions introduced by MySQL, there *is* a point in complaining about the "extended" GROUP BY mode in this case. More specifically, it make sense to complain about its being *enabled by default*. For if it wasn't so, the OP might have learnt sooner what GROUP BY was doing and how it was (probably) not the right tool for them in the first place.

Comment: @AndriyM Yes, that is very true. What was less helpful was pointing the OP to documentation about that feature, the relevance of which would only be obvious to somebody who already understood what was going on. I felt there was an over-eagerness to focus on criticising MySQL rather than explaining to the OP what the problem actually was, and how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

`GROUP BY configuration_name` means "I want one row for each distinct value of `configuration_name`". That means you will only get one row with the `configuration_name` `'Voltage'`.

At the end of your question you mention wanting to "group them next to each other" - that is not what "group" means in an SQL context, but is about the "order" you get the results in. So you want not `GROUP BY configuration_name` but `ORDER BY configuration_name`.

In fact, you probably want to have all the voltages next to each other, but then within those groups, sort the rows based on their timestamp. For that, you just specify multiple columns to order by, in sequence, e.g. `ORDER BY configuration_name, time_stamp` which translates as "sort the results by `configuration_name`, then where that is equal by `time_stamp`".

Comment: My God, I'm so glad I don't use MySQL on a regular basis.  This kind of abomination would drive me over the edge.

Comment: @MaxVernon Please clarify: the information above applies to all DBMSes, and to standard SQL. The only difference is that the OP would have got an error message with the particular approach attempted in other DBMSes; that message would not have included the solution pointed to in this answer.

Comment: I like your answer.  I was merely trying to point out that any SQL interpreter that allows a `GROUP BY` on less fields than are present in the `SELECT` without throwing an error would drive me to drink.

Comment: @MaxVernon Yep, it's definitely not helpful for anyone new to SQL.